# My questions are valid. The users just refrain answering them

Tags: discussion, questions

I ask rational questions but what can I do if users dislike them. Its not upon me to improve them. They make sense. But in reply I get downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

These are *your* questions. If they're unpopular, or unwelcome, it's *entirely* upon you if you want that to change; you can't expect anyone else is going to do that for you.

People vote on questions for their own reasons. People answer questions for their own reasons. Everybody on here is a volunteer, and nobody is *required* to like your stuff, any of it.

There's thousands of questions on the site which have attracted upvotes and useful answers; there's nothing stopping you from just looking through the popular questions and seeing what sorts of questions the community prefers. There's over a decade of advice on Meta here, you can browse for ages and find ways to improve your questions.

Or you can keep posting unpopular and unwelcome questions that make sense to you with no effort to change because "it's not upon me to improve them" and just watch them continue to be unpopular and unwelcome. Your choice.